# how to count time walk, run, biking in android like google fit

Tags: android, google-fit

I want create an app fitness can count time when I walk,run,biking without open app like google fit.Please help me. thanks

Comment: What have you  tried?

Comment: I read some document about detectedActivity but how can I count time when my app close, google fit I can see it.